# Assign a specific number of random rows into datasets in R

Tags: r, random, assign

I have a dataset with 54285 observations. What I need is to assign randomly 50% of the rows into another dataframe, 30% into another dataset, and the rest (20%) into another one. This should be done without duplicates.
This is an example:

```css
data<-data.frame(numbers=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
data
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

What I expect would be:

```css
df1
5
3
8
1
7

df2
2
4
9

df3
6
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the ratio by number of rows in the dataset and `split` the data to divide them in separate dataframes.

```
set.seed(123)
result <- split(data, sample(rep(1:3, nrow(data) * c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2))))
names(result) <- paste0('df', seq_along(result))
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)

df1

#   numbers
#1        1
#3        3
#7        7
#9        9
#10      10

df2
#  numbers
#4       4
#5       5
#8       8

df3
#  numbers
#2       2
#6       6
```

---

For large dataframes using `sample` with `prob` argument should work as well. However, note that this might not give you exact number of rows that you expect like the above `rep` answer.

```
result <- split(data, sample(1:3, nrow(data), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
```